# Facebook SDK: How to redirect after successful login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am a bit confused with `authResponseChange` event.

Once I go to my fb app : `https://apps.facebook.com/f-local`

I get logged in through the cookie on server side automatically and the the moment the Javascript is firing, `if (response.status === 'connected')` is already true.

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') { 
       window.location.reload();
    }        
}
```

The first time it refreshes the site, which I am intending to do. However surprisingly this event keeps firing every time, even though the user is already logged in, hence there shouldn't be any `authResponseChange` in place at all, but yet this keeps firing and it ends up in an infinite loop.

I am quite stuck with this. How do I reload my site only after the first successful login?

Comment: How about redirecting to a separate login page and then to a "logged in" page?

Comment: The problem is redirects on serverside are disallowed the moment you load the canvas. Hence I must render the login part within the same canvas page. You know what I mean?